# Azure Data Factory Lookup activity having issue in reading column names having space

Tags: azure-data-factory

My Lookup activity is having  an excel in blob storage as source data set. It has three columns age, salary and first name like below

| age | salary | first name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 20 | 2000 | Tom |

When I am reading the vaule age from lookup output like below

@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.age

I am getting expected result.

But I am not able to get result for below

@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.first name.

I am getting an error saying invalid template.

Any help here is highly appreciated .

Comment: Can you show us the whole error message?

Answer (score 2):

To specify special characters to Azure Data Factory, we can use [''] instead of . to read such elements, that is:

```
@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow['first name']
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use Lookup active to get the content correctly, but when we want to get the value or the column 'first name', the expression `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.first name` is not valid. The key doesn't support contain the space.

One of way is that please modify the source excel schema, rename or remove the space like this: `first_name`.

Other way is that ship the column name(user range option), let the Data factory create the column for you automatically: `Prop_1, Prop_2,Prop_3,...Prop_n`.

Example data:

[image]

Dataset settings:
[image]

Then you can use the expression like this: `@activity('Lookup1').output.firstRow.Prop_2`.

These maybe a little complex but can resolve the problem.